# XMLファイルにエラーが出る

Tags: android

Androidアプリを作成に関して初心者です．
以下のようなエラーが検出されておりどう対処すればよいかわかりません．

> Error in an XML file: aborting build

追記１）
eclipseで作業をしていて，xmlファイルをにエラーがあります．
xmlファイルのコードの`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`とかいた行に
以下のエラー表示がありました．
原因・対処法わかればお願いします．

エラー表示

> この行で見つかった複数の注釈:- エラー: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
>
> 要素 "ProgressBar" には属性 "android:layout_width" がすでに指定されています。

追記２）

下記のコードが今回質問として投稿しているxmlファイルです．

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sumaryu.SumaryuActivity" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/Progressbar_horizontal"
style="?android:attr/ProgressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="false" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar_small"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:indeterminate="false" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar_large"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

おそらく2個目のProgressBarタグの2行目と4行目が重複しているのだと思います．エラーは2個目のProgressBarタグの4行目の行がエラー表示されているという状況です．

追記３）

xmlファイルのエラーはなくなりました．しかし，なくなったと同時にjavaファイルにエラーが検出されました．詳細は以下の通りです．

```xml
package com.example.sumaryu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class SumaryuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sumaryu);

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_horizontal);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(30);
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(70);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sumaryu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

エラーの場所は，コード中の真ん中周辺にある
「ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_horizontal);」の行です．

エラー内容が，
「progressbar_horizontal は解決できないか、フィールドではありません」
と表示されます．

Comment: エラーログはこれだけですか？　情報が少なすぎて何とも回答のしようがないです。XMLファイルの記述にエラーがあるようですが、そのXMLファイルがどのXMLを指しているのか、なぜエラーになっているのかなどが何もわからないからです。

Comment: エラーに書かれている通り、同じタグに対して `android:layout_width` という属性を複数指定していませんか？でなければ、エラーになっているXMLファイル（あまりに長ければエラーの前後数行）を貼り付けていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `<RelativeLayout ...` の行が重複していたので取り除きましたが、実際には重複していないですよね？

Comment: はい．その通りです．表示されないと思って間違えて二回書いてしまいました．コードの編集ありがたいです．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlのidがProgressbar_horizontalなのに対しコードではprogressbar_horizontalになっています。
大文字か小文字かの問題です。

Answer (score 1):

もしかして
誤　style="?android:attr/ProgressBarStyleHorizontal"
正　style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
っていう単純な間違いじゃないですよね？

Comment: 確かに，間違えていました．ご指摘ありがとうございます．
しかし，その部分の修正だけではエラーの改善まではいたりませんでした．

Answer (score 1):

> おそらく2個目のProgressBarタグの2行目と4行目が重複しているのだと思います．エラーは2個目のProgressBarタグの4行目の行がエラー表示されているという状況です．

XMLでは同じ属性を複数書くことはできません。実際今回の場合、`android:layout_width` に期待される値が `fill_parent` なのか `wrap_content` なのかが、XMLを見ただけではわからないですよね？

正しい方を残して、もう片方を消せばいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 2個目のProgressBarタグの4行目であるandroid:layout_width="wrap_content"を削除したところxmlファイルのエラーはなくなりました．ありがとうございます．しかし，javaファイルにエラーが検出されました．
エラーの詳細は追記3に書きます．

Comment: @ando-rei 横やりすみません。「progressbar_horizontal は解決できないか、フィールドではありません」は単純に「progress」の「P」が大文字か小文字かの違いだったりしませんか？